# Convert from hexadecimal to binary C++

Tags: c++, binary, hex

This kind of builds up on [Already asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483609/how-can-i-convert-hex-numbers-to-binary-in-c)...
However here, say, I'm given a hexadecimal input which could be a max of '0xFFFF'
I'll need it converted to binary, so that I'd end up with a max of 16 bits.

I was wondering if using 'bitset' it'd be quite simple.. Any ideas?

**EDIT :**

After getting answers, improvised piece of code here : http://pastebin.com/f7a6f0a69

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "hexadecimal input". Is it the string `"0xFFFF"`?

Comment: What do you mean to binary? Everything is in binary on a computer, including hex values, floats, ASCII and Unicode characters. Do you mean to a scalar/integer?

Comment: By binary, I meant "In physical bits" ..

Comment: Since you don't seem to understand that Sothern's question. It may be better if you cut/paste the original question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Supposing by "hexadecimal input" you mean a string containing a hexadecimal number, then this would work:

```
const char* const str = "0xFFFF";
std::istringstream iss(str);
int i;
iss >> std::hex >> i;
if(!iss && !iss.eof()) throw "dammit!";
std::cout << '"' << str << "\": " << i << "(0x" << std::hex << i << ")\n";
```

Comment: Well, that was awesome. But I didn't need it in decimal, I needed it in binary. Anyway, I researched a bit and did the improvisation.. :) Here : http://pastebin.com/m401f1b79

Comment: @halluc1nati0n: I would advice you to be more precise in your questions wording. Any variable is actually binary, and after `iss >> std::hex >> i` the value is actually in binary form. Now, what you were requesting is converting to a string representing the binary form, which is a different story. I am sure you would have gotten the result in the first place had you asked the appropriate question.

Comment: @dribeas : I agree that it was a 'poor choice of words' on my part, but it did help me do my own improvisation on the code. Which is what Stack Overflow epitomizes, in a way. And moreover, I've already acknowledged this by choosing what 'sbi' gave as the 'correct' answer!