# Char array to binary

Tags: c++

i want read & copy all bytes from txt file:

```
char * my_bytes = txtfile.txt; // for example
unsigned char binary[] = { my_bytes};
```

inside txtfile.txt: // its about 120 bytes

```
0x41, 0x10, 0xF0, 0x50 etc...
```

I know how to read file, but can't figure out how to copy it into binary
and binary should be :

```
binary[120] = { my_bytes }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert hexadecimal numbers to binary in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483609/how-can-i-convert-hexadecimal-numbers-to-binary-in-c)

Comment: You're reading hex values into a character array. Read them as bytes instead. Then convert the hex values into binary using the link I provided.

Comment: It isn't clear what the problem is. Please post a [mcve].