# C ++: library for conversion, Ex: binary -> decimal | binary -> hexadecimal etc

Tags: c++, converters

for my project i need to convert some numbers, exemple:

1. Binary --> decimal
2. Decimal--> binary
3. Binary --> hexadecimal
4. Hexadecimal --> binary
5. Etc...

I tried to create some functios, but it's long operation and i immediately need a converter.

Someone know a library for do this, then, where do i find it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert hexadecimal numbers to binary in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483609/how-can-i-convert-hexadecimal-numbers-to-binary-in-c)

Comment: Not clear if you need to convert numbers or to and from strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example some steps involving strings and numbers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    auto binary = std::stoi("0110", nullptr, 2);
    auto hex = std::stoi("f", nullptr,  16);

    assert(binary == 6);
    assert(hex == 15);

    std::stringstream os;

    os << std::hex << hex;  // todo add formatters.
    std::cout << os.str() << std::endl;

    std::bitset<4> bits{ binary };
    std::cout << bits.to_string() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks you, you were helpful

Comment: Ok, but is ther a metod for convert from hexadecimal to binary and the revers

Comment: You mean directly from string to string? No, but you can easily build them for yourself from the code snippets in the answers here

Answer (score 0):

You can use stoi function to convert values in binary/hex/octal format to decimal number:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string hex("BAF");
  std::string bin("1111");
  std::string octal("734");

  std::cout << "Hex: " << hex << " => " << std::stoi(hex, 0, 16) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Bin: " << bin << " => " << std::stoi(bin, 0, 2) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Octal: " << octal << " => " << std::stoi(octal, 0, 8)
            << std::endl;
}
```

For other conversions (from decimal to binary/hex/octal) you should implement your own function. You can use std::bitset to help you with that.

Comment: Ok, thanks you, you were helpful

Comment: Ok, but is ther a metod for convert from hexadecimal to binary and the revers